# Как правильно составить запросы команд insert/update/delete для обновления связанных таблиц в исходной БД?

Tags: c#, база-данных, ole, oledb

Имеется БД с такой структурой (упрощенной):

[image]

В моей программе выводится одна из этих таблиц с возможностью редактировать содержимое (я использую WinForm). Рядом находится кнопка, которая передаёт изменённую таблицу обратно в БД.

Проблема в том, что если использовать генерированные команды (OleDbCommandBuilder), то при отправке данных в БД получаю ошибку с указанием столбцов из других таблиц.

Например. Если я что-то меняю в таблице "болезни": В DataTable "Table" отсутствует DataColumn "Номер больного" для данного SourceColumn "Номер больного".

Если что-то меняю в таблицу "посещения": ошибка синтаксиса INSERT INTO. Или тоже самое с командами UPDATE или DELETE.

Очевидно, что нужно составлять команды вручную. Но из примеров на MSDN не ясно, как описывать связи между таблицами. Сами статьи:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdataadapter.insertcommand(v=vs.110).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdataadapter.updatecommand(v=vs.110).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdataadapter.deletecommand(v=vs.110).aspx

Собственно, помогите составить правильные команды для таблиц "болезни" и "посещения". Или хотя бы объясните принцип.

Ещё лучше, если вам известен более простой способ.

Если это важно, подготовка формы:

```
protected string conStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=db.mdb";
protected OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
protected OleDbDataAdapter adapter;
protected OleDbCommandBuilder cBuilder;

DataSet dataSet;

public Form1() {
    InitializeComponent();
    connection.ConnectionString = conStr;
    adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME", connection);
    dataSet = new DataSet();
    cBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter);
    adapter.Fill(dataSet);

    connection.Open();
    adapter.UpdateCommand = cBuilder.GetUpdateCommand(true);
    adapter.InsertCommand = cBuilder.GetInsertCommand(true);
    connection.Close();
}
```

Сохраняю данные из таблицы в БД:

```
private void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    adapter.Update(dataSet);
}
```

Метод загрузки, вроде бы, не имеет значения.

---

Было ошибкой использовать MS Access. Поскольку, в данной ситуации, я не могу выбрать другую БД, придётся использовать другое решение.

Comment: Использовать Entity Framework (EF) нельзя?

Comment: @cpp_user, хм, можно. Завтра посмотрю.

Comment: @cpp_user, выглядит довольно хлопотно. Не поделитесь примером использования для подобной цели?

Comment: В вашем случае быстрее будет выбрать в EF - Database First - вам сгенерируются С# классы - а далее смотрите примеры CRUD операций в EF. Подробнее здесь: http://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/index.php

Comment: @cpp_user, забыл указать важную деталь. Мне обязательно нужно работать с базой MS Access, и, насколько понял, EF не совместим с ним.

Comment: Даже не знаю какой смысл использовать в наше время MS Access, когда есть MS SQL Server Express (with support LocalDB). Но дело ваше конечно.

Comment: @cpp_user, просто, это учебный проект и заранее было согласовано использование MS Access. Выбирал СУБД сам и не думал, что с ней будут проблемы. В таком случае лучше отказаться от таблицы и придраться к ТЗ. Спасибо за консультацию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Но потом до меня дошло:

```
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand v_insertCommand = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Посещения " +
                "([Номер больного], [Номер врача], [Номер болезни], Дата) " +
                "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", connection);
            v_insertCommand.Parameters.Add("Номер больного", OleDbType.Integer, 10, "Номер больного");
            v_insertCommand.Parameters.Add("Номер врача", OleDbType.Integer, 10, "Номер врача");
            v_insertCommand.Parameters.Add("Номер болезни", OleDbType.Integer, 10, "Номер болезни");
            v_insertCommand.Parameters.Add("Дата", OleDbType.DBDate, 10, "Дата");
            adapter.InsertCommand = v_insertCommand;
            connection.Close();

            adapter.Update(dataSet);
```

Все остальные запросы по аналогии. Для ключей можно указывать тип `OleDbType.Integer`.